# Синхронизация Vagrant + Virtualbox с рабочими папками

Tags: php, virtualbox, vagrant

Подскажите новичку как начать работу с Vagrant. Я установил все, VirtualBox, Vagrant, все работает, не могу понять как синхронизировать файлы, а именно чтобы у себя на Mac создать папку, и чтобы она была так же в виртуальной машине Ununtu. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для синхронизации файлов между гостевой-системой и хост-системой Vagrant использует Синхронизированные Каталоги ([Synced Folders](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/)). По умолчанию Vagrant устанавливает связь между каталогом, в котором лежит Vagrantfile хост-системы и каталогом `/vagrant` гостевой системы. При желании, вы можете изменить синхронизируемые каталоги в Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Устанавливаем связь между каталогом "./src" хост-системы
  # и каталогом "/home/vagrant" гостевой системы.
  config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/home/vagrant"
end
```

Существует несколько различных способов синхронизации каталогов. Если я не ошибаюсь, то предпочтительным способом синхронизации является утилита `rsync`.

Сама синхронизации происходит при выполнении команд `vagrant up` и `vagrant reload`. Для того, чтобы отслеживать изменения в "реальном времени" вам нужно выполнить в консоли хост-системы команду:

```
vagrant rsync-auto
```

Это позволит автоматически переносить изменения, сделанные в файлах хост-системы в гостевую систему.

Подробнее о команде `rsync-auto` можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync-auto.html).

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!Вот от души. Очень помогло!